Is there an org-mode code block that echoes its content back?
Is there a code block type in org-mode that can echo its context (text) back when executed?
So, in pseudo-code, the code block:
#+begin_src echo
{ "id": 1, "name": "James Brown"}
#+end_src

, when C-c C-c, should generate the text within it as the result:
{ "id": 1, "name": "James Brown"}

My main goal is to use this as a starting point for making the Unix pipeline work among org-mode code blocks. Basically, the result of this "echo" block should be used as the input for another block (e.g. a shell block).
I tried text and json mode etc., but the common problem is that they don't execute. With C-c C-c, they generate warnings such as No org-babel-execute function for text!
(This is with Emacs 29 under Ubuntu 24.04 LTS)

This will echo the echo block back

(defun org-babel-execute:echo (body params)
  "Echo back the BODY of the source block."
  body)

